# File reading and parsing peformance for IronPython vs CPython

Tags: python, ironpython

I've been working on a file reader in python where I expect to read ascii files ~100MB.  There is a bunch of header information at the top and then just tab delimited columns.  Some columns contain non numeric data (which I don't care about right now).  I have a matlab implementation that reads a 30MB sample file in less than 1.5sec.  My python reader takes about 2 sec in CPython, but about 4 seconds in IronPython.  The difference appears to be where the string values get converted floats, but I haven't been able to make it go faster in IronPython.

My latest iteration here has the following loop to read and parse the lines

```
#-Parse the actual data lines
istep = -1
while len(line) > 0:

    istep += 1
    #-Split the line and convert pasred values to floats
    timestep = line.split();            
    for ichan in numericChannels:                    
        data[ichan].append(float(timestep[ichan]))

    line = f.readline().strip()
```

`numericChannels` is a list of integers specifying which channels I want to read.  `data` is a list of lists where is sub list is a column of data.

The difference in performance seems to be coming from the float conversion.  Any ideas on what I can do on IronPython to speed this up?  I've even tried reading the file a head of time then using the System.Threading.Task.Parallel.ForEach construct to parse the file lines.  That didn't help at all.

Thanks.

Comment: If it takes 4 seconds to run your code as-is, how long does it take if you remove the `float` function call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems IronPython is just slower than CPython for reading text files.  I ran this snippet in several versions of Python (the partest2.txt file has 200,000 numbers given on one row):

```
import sys
import timeit

tmr = timeit.Timer("with open(r'partest2.txt','r') as fid:fid.readlines()")
res = tmr.timeit(number=20)
print(res)
```

Results:

- CPython 2.7 : 1.282
- CPython 3.3 : 1.562
- IronPython 2.6 [.NET 2]: 2.196
- IronPython 2.7 [.NET 4]: 2.880

The IronPython runs spit out this warning (not sure if it affects anything):

> < string>:1: RuntimeWarning: IronPython has no support for disabling
>   the GC

When the file being read (partest2.txt) is changed so that it has the same 200,000 numbers each given on it's own line here are the timings (quite different)

- CPython 2.7 : 4.04
- CPython 3.3 : 7.61
- IronPython 2.7 [.NET 4]: 20.22
- IronPython 2.6 [.NET 2]: 21.46

YIKES!

Answer (score 0):

a) you say "The difference appears to be where the string values get converted floats" - what makes you think that? Have you run a profiler on the code?

b) if you have the memory it may be faster to just do

```
for line in f.readlines():
```

Comment: Yes, I have done some profiling of this.  I've tried reading the file lines into memory (takes about 0.5sec up front) and doesn't make much of a difference otherwise.  I thought the same thing.  That loop is the sticking point whether or not I have the file already in memory or not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that something like this *might* be a little faster.

```
import operator
data=[]
istep = -1
columngetter=operator.itemgetter(*numericChannels)
while len(line) > 0:
    istep += 1
    #-Split the line and convert parsed values to floats
    timestep = line.split()
    data.append(map(float,columngetter(timestep)))
    line = f.readline().strip()

data=zip(*data)
```